# Xpages Copy Attachment from current document to new document

Tags: xpages, mime-types, attachment, document

I am having a xpage in which the document having multiple attachments, I want to copy one selected attachment to fresh new document to process it furthur.

So now, So far i am able get the selected attachment in a NotesEmbeddedObject.I have a button and the onclick script is..

Code:

```
 var attachmentDoc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByUNID(currentDocId);
  // where currentDocId is the document with all the attachments.
 var attchment:NotesEmbeddedObject=attachmentDoc.getAttachment("someFile.txt");
 // Just to verify
 if(attchment == null){
 view.postScript("alert('Attachment not Exist')");
 }else{
  view.postScript("alert('"+attchment +"')");
 }
```

The above code work perfect.It means now I have the attachment now.Now my task is to copy this to new document.

I have given a try by research is.

```
  // in above else 
var doc_new_attach:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var mimeRoot:NotesMIMEEntity=doc_new_attach.getMIMEEntity("Body");
var child:NotesMIMEEntity=mimeRoot.createChildEntity();
var is = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(attchment.getInputStream());
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
stream.setContents(is);
child.setContentFromBytes(stream, attchment.getType(),NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
```

Actually i am bad with notes Rich-text, the another way to acheive this is which I feel easier is Document.copyAllItems(Document doc, boolean replace) and than removing what is unnecessary. But want to know how to copy and add the selected attchment to other document.

Any suggestion would be really appreciate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get selective attachment from one document to other,

Code:

```
 session.setConvertMime(false);
 var attachmentDoc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByUNID(currentDocId);
  // where currentDocId is the document with all the attachments.
 var attchment:NotesEmbeddedObject=attachmentDoc.getAttachment("someFile.txt");
 // Just to verify
 if(attchment == null){
     view.postScript("alert('Attachment not Exist')");
 }
 else
 {
     var fileName = "someFile.txt";
     var doc_new_attach:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();  
     var body:NotesMIMEEntity= doc_new_attach.createMIMEEntity(fileName);
     var bodyHeader:NotesMIMEHeader = body.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
     var isHeaderValSet = bodyHeader.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");    
    if (!isHeaderValSet) {
         throw new ComponentException("Could not set MIME header value.");
    }
    var is = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(attchment.getInputStream());   
    var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
    stream.setContents(is);

    var mimeType = "text/csv"; 
    body.setContentFromBytes(stream, mimeType, 1730);    
    doc_new_attach.replaceItemValue("Form","AttachmentTesting");
    doc_new_attach.save(false);

    session.setConvertMime(true);
 }
```

In above code I have hard coded the "mimeType" as i am not able to get content-type from the document which contains the acttachment and "attchment.getType();" returns "Interger" which is not eccepted by "mimeType". Can help me to get the content type. 
Otherwise rest all perfectly working to get and put the attachment which I needed from one document to other.

Answer (score 0):

`Document.copyItem(Item)` may be what you need, to copy the specified `Item` into the specified `Document`.

Comment: Yes, Probably Document.copyItem(Item) will help me to get the item from that document, for example by Document.copyItem(Item), I will able get all the attachments from the document but actually I want only one selected attachment from the item.I got the solution for this,Please check the answer I have posted and correct me if I am wrong.